# Trigger Snapshot just before build in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

We need to setup a snapshot dependency in TeamCity that runs just before the dependant build starts.

Currently we have the problem that the snapshot maybe taken 30 minutes before the build starts. (The build starts later due to other factors). Ideally we want the snapshot to be taken and then the dependant build to immediately start.

Is this possible in TeamCity? Is there another way to achieve a similar thing.

Comment: can you share your current build setup and what's not working as expected? It's not clear at all to me from the question

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines I'm guessing the problem here is that the dependent build isn't always run immediately when it's snapshot dependency finishes because an agent isn't always available. If that's the case then my suggestion would be to merge the two builds into a single build configuration as that will ensure that all the steps occur with no delay in between.